# Extend sum function implementation Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp

I have a sum function written in Rcpp. It works on numeric data. I am trying to extend it to work on lists datatype(in R).

R version: R-3.5.3 (Rtools35, mingw_64 c++11 compiler)

```
library('Rcpp')
library('RcppArmadillo')
    
cppFunction('double sumCPP(arma::vec& obj){
  // Input
  // Numeric vector : Integer / Double: 
    // sumCPP(c(1L, 6L, 10L))
    // sumCPP(c(1L, 6.5, 10L))
    // sumCPP(c(1, 6, 10))

  double result;
  result = arma::accu(obj);
  return result;
}',depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

Output:

```
> sumCPP(c(1L, 6L, 10L))
[1] 17
```

list data (using education expenditure data set)

```
education <- read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/robustbase/education.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(education) <- c("X","State","Region","Urban.Population","Per.Capita.Income","Minor.Population","Education.Expenditures")
education['Minor.Population']
```

Result from the inbuilt sum function in R

```
> sum(education['Minor.Population'])
[1] 16287
```

My sum function implementation in Rcpp and RcppArmadillo

```
Error in sumCPP(education["Minor.Population"]) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
```

I came across a workaround, but this would require knowing the type beforehand and I am not planning to use this.

```
> sumCPP(unlist(education['Minor.Population']))
[1] 16287
```

I don't have much experience with C++ but here is the pseudocode. The parameter to the sumV2CPP function(trying to use c++ stl to create a general function) can be numeric data or list(VECSXP type). Then I use typeid to find the type of input and do the sum in the if else condition. Can someone help with this.

```
cppFunction('double sumV2CPP(pass_paramater_here){
  #include <typeinfo>

  template <typename T>
  std::string the_type(T a_variable) {
      
      std::double result;
      
      if (typeid(T) == typeid(arma::vec)) {
      // calculate interger/double vector sum
              result = arma::accu(obj);
      } else if(typeid(T) == typeid(Rcpp::List)) {
      // calculate list sum with for loop
              result = list_sum; 
          }
      }
      return result;
}', depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `typeid()` like you did. But also in C++ if you have static type then you can use `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, arma::vec>)`, it may be faster because this comparison is `constexpr` hence doesn't create any run-time check, while `typeid()` may check at run time. To use `std::is_same_v` you have to `#include <type_traits>`.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to make the input always a vector of doubles in R and leave your RCPP function as it is. Presumably ``sumCPP(education['Minor.Population'][,1])`` works?

Comment: This is a fairly standard programming problem for Rcpp too: you have something that works on a vector, now you want it on list wrapping around a vectro -- just look at the basic `Rcpp::List` examples at the Rcpp Gallery, or even in the `rcppexamples` package on how to access elements from a list ... which you can then treat columnwise.